# What is the significance or benefit of chanting Maha Mrityunjay Mantra?

Tags: mantras, culture, spirituality

[*Maha Mrityunjaya Mantra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahamrityunjaya_Mantra):

> ॐ त्र्यम्बकं यजामहे सुगन्धिं पुष्टिवर्धनम्
>   उर्वारुकमिव बन्धनान्मृत्योर्मुक्षीय माऽमृतात्
>     ...
>   tryambakaṃ yajāmahe sugandhiṃ puṣṭivardhanam
>   urvārukamiva bandhanānmṛtyormukṣīya mā'mṛtāt

Comment: [Significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahamrityunjaya_Mantra#Significance). Plz put some more info in the body of the Qn as edited now.