# What are the exact benefits of Mahamrityunjaya Mantra?

Tags: shiva, mantras

I want to know about the benefits of Mahamrityunjaya Mantra and what are the good times to chant Shiva mantra.

Comment: Duplicate of [I want to know the exact explanation of Maha Mrityunjaya Mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10741/21103) as [What is the significance or benefit of chanting Maha Mrityunjay Mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19552/21103) has been marked a duplicate of the former?

Comment: No, none of those answer this question. @SeverusSnape Leaving this one open.

Comment: The second question was closed (by some high-rep and experienced users) without addressing the benefits :) I thought it is because "benefits" as asked in the second question can be addressed using opinions whereas "significance" was already covered in the first. Again, yes, this question has asked "time" too. @sv.

Answer (score 1):

The merits of worshipping Mahamrityunjaya mantra are given in Shiva Purana

> 22. The Mṛtyuñjaya mantra shall be repeated half a million times when Śiva shall be visible to the devotee and fulfil his desires.

> 23. If a person repeats the mantra a hundred thousand times and begins a second instalment **he will be lifted to a higher caste**. When he completes the third hundred thousand times all **his worldly desires will be fulfilled**. In the fourth Lakṣa he **will be able to see the lord.**

> 24. When the fifty Lakṣa is completed, **the lord will confer on him all benefits.** When the same mantra is repeated a million times, **the merit is tremendous.**

> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225982.html

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the Mahamrityunjaya Mantra Benefits And Importance that can change your life.**
Lord Shiva’s Mahamrityunjaya Mantra is a Sanskrit mantra which not only cures your bodily well-being but also aligns your psychological and psychological peace with your wellness.
This Mahamrityunjaya Mantra Jaap helps you reevaluate your bodily, psychological, and psychological state since it’s thought it is a moksha mantra; you speech to Lord Shiva, searching for his blessing to publicize your wellbeing and stop you and your nearest and dearest from premature passing. Aside from this, There Are Numerous other [Mahamrityunjaya Mantra Benefits](https://vedastrologer.com/mahamrityunjay-mantra/)

1.This mantra can help the health of a sick person. You can sit next to some sick or an ailing patient and chant this mantra 108 times and search Lord Shiva’s blessing for the individual’s wellbeing and well-being. It’s believed that the chanting of this mantra produces a particular kind of vibration that wards off all wicked, realigns the body, and restores good health.
2.The mantra helps you attract your physical, mental, and emotional state all set up; all aligned together. Be sure that you close the top of the glass with all the palm of your right hand and chant the mantra 108 times. Once you are finished, you can spray the water in the house or you may even give the water to individuals in the home for drinking.
3.One of the main reasons why this mantra is so powerful and important is because it helps your body connect with your inner self; this mantra provides spiritual upliftment.
4.The chanting od the screenplay can also help individuals who have any kind of’dosha’ in their’Kundli’ (horoscope)
5. This advantage is not very well known but chanting with this Shiva Jaap can actually ward off all of your financial troubles.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Welcome to Hindism Stack Exchange. https://vedastrologer.com looks like a blog. We insist on some authentic sources to be cited. See [what kind of sources are acceptable](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277)